# How to show the value of the group column in the page header in BIRT?

Tags: birt

I am trying to develop a report where I need to group employees by department and break them across pages by department. However the department ID needs to be displayed in the page header instead of the group header row.

I looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw_k1qHY_gU) and developed a sample report.

Following is the sample CSV

```
DEPT_ID,EMP_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
1,1,John,Smith
1,2,Jane,Smith
1,3,David,Warner
2,4,Francis,Kilgore
2,5,Peter,Muller
2,6,Jonathan,Border
2,7,Timothy,Sanchez
3,8,Julia,Wesson
3,9,Carl,Spencer
3,10,Jackie,Lee
```

Created a report based on the above data having a group on DEPT_ID.

I have created a page variable `deptID`.
Following is the code on onPageCreate of the report

```
reportContext.setPageVariable("deptID", null);
```

Following is the code on the department group header data element

```
if(reportContext.getPageVariable("deptID") == null) {
    reportContext.setPageVariable("deptID", value);
}
```

Added the `deptID` page variable by going to the master page and dragging and dropping the "Variable" from the pallete on the page header.

The report works fine and I am able to see the Dept ID in the page header as long as the dept group is not hidden. However, as soon as I hide the dept group (since I do not want to show it), the variable can no longer be seen on the page header.

Is there anything else I need to be doing or any other approach I need to follow?